# Combining a table from multiple workbooks into one master workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to combine a table from multiple workbooks and create one big master workbook.

What I've done so far:

1. I created a blank workbook called "Master" with a sheet name " total" to paste the extracted data into.
   I created VBA in this workbook.
2. I have more than 100 source files from which I want to extract a table.
   They are all in the same directory: "C:\Users\Documents\Test".
   The sheets are named "Sheet1".

To create the master workbook, I'd like to locate the last row and start copying new values from the next spreadsheet.
Each table from different workbooks contains its own header (column names) and I want to skip the headers from the second file.
The tables are located in A1:N53 in each workbook.

My code:

```vb
Private Sub Extraction()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wkbDest As Workbook
Dim wkbSource As Workbook
Set wkbDest = ThisWorkbook
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim strExtension As String

Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\Documents\Test\"
strExtension = Dir(strPath & "*.xls*")

Do While strExtension <> ""
    Set wkbSource = Workbooks.Open(strExtension)
    With wkbSource
        LastRow = .Sheets("total").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        .Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:N3" & LastRow).Copy wkbDest.Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        .Close savechanges:=False
    End With
    strExtension = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This executes script from master file. It uses `DIR()` to loop over all files inside directory and calls the Resize sub procedure to obtain and transfer the values from range "A1:N53" into master file.

`DIR()` will iterate through all files inside filepath. For each file, it will grab the data in sheets(1) range("A1:N53"). (Change to range("A2:N53") if you don't want header included.)

Once the data is obtained through the range, the script will resize the range and transfer the value into Sheets (master) based on last row count.

```vb
Option Explicit

Dim fpath As String
Dim fname As String

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim twb As Workbook

Dim rgSrc As Range
Dim rgDest As Range

Sub foo()
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    fpath = "C:\Users\Documents\Test\"
    fname = Dir(fpath)

    Do While fname <> ""
        Set twb = Workbooks.Open(fpath & fname)
        Call Resize
        twb.Close
        fname = Dir()
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub


Private Sub Resize()

    ' Get all the data in the current region?change it to "A2:N53" is you dont want header included from the files in filepath
    Set rgSrc = twb.Sheets(1).Range("A1:N53")
    'Get the range destination
    Set rgDest = wb.Sheets("Master").Cells(wb.Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1, 1)
    Set rgDest = rgDest.Resize(rgSrc.Rows.Count, rgSrc.Columns.Count)
    rgDest.Value2 = rgSrc.Value2

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @victor song, thank you so much but could you give me more details about the last part of you code? I ran into an error saying "subscript out of range" for  crow = wbs.sheets(s).cells(rows.count,c).end(xlup).row. Could you explain what this line does?

Comment: Updates done -- I have removed the private function and just wrote it directly in the line since I was only using it once. Please let me know if the script works, or if it needs some adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following code that I have been using for some time and appears to be working fine. The promptbox will ask you to select the files and will combine all of them into a stacked database. It will also add a filename so that you can identify the filename from where the data was picked. Code below - Let me know if this helps -

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetCurrentDirectoryA Lib _
    "kernel32" (ByVal lpPathName As String) As Long

Sub ChDirNet(szPath As String)
    SetCurrentDirectoryA szPath
End Sub


Sub MergeSpecificWorkbooks()
    Dim MyPath As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, FNum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long
    Dim SaveDriveDir As String
    Dim FName As Variant
    Dim FirstCell As String



    ' Set application properties.
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    SaveDriveDir = CurDir
    ' Change this to the path\folder location of the files.
    ChDirNet "C:\Users\nik\test"

    FName = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*", _
                                        MultiSelect:=True)
    If IsArray(FName) Then

        ' Add a new workbook with one sheet.
        Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
        rnum = 1


        ' Loop through all files in the myFiles array.
        For FNum = LBound(FName) To UBound(FName)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(FName(FNum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then

                On Error Resume Next
                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                   FirstCell = "A1"
                   Set sourceRange = .Range(FirstCell & ":" & RDB_Last(3, .Cells))
                   ' Test if the row of the last cell is equal to or greater than the row of the first cell.
                   If RDB_Last(1, .Cells) < .Range(FirstCell).Row Then
                      Set sourceRange = Nothing
                   End If
                End With



                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    ' If the source range uses all columns then
                    ' skip this file.
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the target worksheet."
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close SaveChanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        ' Copy the file name in column A.
                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = FName(FNum)
                        End With

                        ' Set the destination range.
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        ' Copy the values from the source range
                        ' to the destination range.
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value
                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close SaveChanges:=False
            End If

        Next FNum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    ' Restore the application properties.
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
    ChDirNet SaveDriveDir
End Sub



Function RDB_Last(choice As Integer, rng As Range)

' A choice of 1 = last row.
' A choice of 2 = last column.
' A choice of 3 = last cell.
   Dim lrw As Long
   Dim lcol As Integer

   Select Case choice

   Case 1:
      On Error Resume Next
      RDB_Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                          LookAt:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row
      On Error GoTo 0

   Case 2:
      On Error Resume Next
      RDB_Last = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                          LookAt:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Column
      On Error GoTo 0

   Case 3:
      On Error Resume Next
      lrw = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                    After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                    MatchCase:=False).Row
      On Error GoTo 0

      On Error Resume Next
      lcol = rng.Find(What:="*", _
                     After:=rng.Cells(1), _
                     LookAt:=xlPart, _
                     LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                     SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                     SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                     MatchCase:=False).Column
      On Error GoTo 0

      On Error Resume Next
      RDB_Last = rng.Parent.Cells(lrw, lcol).Address(False, False)
      If Err.Number > 0 Then
         RDB_Last = rng.Cells(1).Address(False, False)
         Err.Clear
      End If
      On Error GoTo 0

   End Select
End Function
```